# how to monitor heap size of managed server using java

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, weblogic, heap-memory

I want to test the performance of my Java application deployed on web logic managed server.I am interested in monitoring heap size getting used on managed sever for the application.how can i achieve this using JMeter or VMVisual.
does anyone have the demo for above scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways to monitor the Heap of a managed server.

1. Using weblogic admin console
2. WLST
3. Custom JMX client
4. VisualVM/Jconsole (other java pro-filers).

You can find lots of examples for each of the above methods. For monitoring using visual VM (or Jconsole etc) you need two things.

Step 1: Enable JMX in you Managed Server by adding the below JVM arguments to your Managed server start up command

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9052 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djavax.management.builder.initial=weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerBuilder
```

The above arguments let the server listen for JMX connection in port 9052. Please note for simplicity purpose the authentication is disabled. Its advisable to enable authentication if its a production system.

Step 2: Connect via VisualVM ( or another JMX clients) to the above port

In VisualVM
a. create new Remote host ( give full hostname of the system in which you have the managed server running)

b. Right click the hosted created by above step and select add JMX connection
c. In the New JMX connection window Specify the port as 8500 ( mentioned in the step 1).

The below thread has  more  details (though this is specific for SOA it will work as it internally uses weblogic).
http://oraclefusionfacts.blogspot.in/2012/01/monitoring-remote-jvms-using-jvisualvm.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to login to WebLogic Enterprise Manager, accessible through the path http://server:port/em (instead of /console), there are features there that allow you to monitor JVM heap and non-heap monitoring.